# NodeJS - Mongoose update mongodb document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I've got a MongoDb, created some MongoDb entries in NodeJS and want to update some of the MongoDb documents with NodeJS now.

**That is how a document in the database looks like:**

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5a035628fa35d9190cebca09"), 
"start" : {
    "city" : "Dortmund", 
    "zipcode" : "475758", 
    "datetime" : "2017-11-09T07:00", 
    "street" : "Umbacherweg 345"
}, 
"destination" : {
    "city" : "Köln", 
    "zipcode" : "51105", 
    "datetime" : "2017-11-10T07:00", 
    "street" : "Testreet 24"
}, 
"baseData" : {
    "isOffer" : true, 
    "name" : "Kadir Badir", 
    "email" : "kadir.badir@gmail.com", 
    "mobilenumber" : "018747578", 
    "description" : "gteg", 
    "costs" : "2,00€", 
    "freeplacesamount" : "2", 
    "personID" : "fiazt_45666", 
    "created" : ISODate("2017-11-08T19:08:24.540+0000")
}
```

}

**That is how I generate the document that I want to push later on:**

```
var objToUse = {
            "_id" : baseData.offerID,
            "start": {
                "city": postedStart.city,
                "zipcode": postedStart.zipcode,
                "datetime": postedStart.datetime,
                "street": postedStart.street,
            },
            "destination": {
                "city": postedEnd.city,
                "zipcode": postedEnd.zipcode,
                "datetime": postedEnd.datetime,
                "street": postedEnd.street,
            },
            "baseData": {
                "isOffer": baseData.isOffer,
                "name": baseData.name,
                "email": baseData.email,
                "mobilenumber": baseData.mobilenumber,
                "description": baseData.description,
                "costs": baseData.costs,
                "freeplacesamount": baseData.freeplacesamount,

                "personID": currUser.ID,
                "created": new Date()
            }
        };
```

```js
database.collection(toInsertDb).findOneAndUpdate(
                  { "_id": new ObjectId(objToUse.baseData.offerID)},
                  {objToUse},
                    function(err, result) {
                        assert.equal(err, null);
                        console.log("Edited a document in the collection.");
                       
                    });
```

But the document in the database stays unchanged. Can you help me?

I'm not 100% sure if findOneAndUpdate is the right method...

Comment: `objToUse.baseData.offerID` appears to be empty. Also you actually mean `objToUse` as the second argument and not `{ objToUse }`. That latter form you did means `{ "objToUse": objToUse }` as an ES6 shorthand assignment for *"create me an object with the 'key name' of the variable assigning the variable's context to that 'key'"*. Classic 'cargo cult' of code.

Comment: Thank you! That was the solution!